# HAProxy: How to match on hostname instead of the IP address

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to match the `host` request header and use appropriate backend to route the request.

This is what I want to match on (which does not work):

```
acl from_external_url req.hdr(Host) -i mydomain.com  

# Chrome dev tools network tab does show mydomain.com set as the Host header
```

However, matching to a direct IP address works (which I don't want):

```
acl from_external_url req.hdr(Host) -i 22.22.22.22
```

So, how do I make HAProxy route on hostname instead of the IP?

Update 1:

```
use_backend oid_external if from_external_url
use_backend oid_internal if !from_external_url
```

Comment: *"Chrome dev tools network tab does show mydomain.com set as the Host header"*  Why not? What does it show?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am saying that it DOES show the correct hostname instead of the IP

Comment: Wow, I guess reading is hard.  I'd swear aI looked twice, saw "does not" both times.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: This is doubly confusing, because there's no obvious explanation at all for matching against the IP address working... that should *not* work... although you haven't shown where you're testing the ACL to select a backend.  An unintended/misplaced `!` or accidentally using `unless` (instead of `if`) would potentially explain it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have updated the Question with backend information as well. When I use the IP address format both backends work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below way to route based on hostname which works as I have about 12 sites going through haproxy.

```
acl host_mydomain.com hdr(host) -i mydomain.com
use_backend oid_external if host_mydomain.com
```